# GDI+ DashStyle throws OutOfMemoryException in .NET

Tags: .net, winforms, gdi+, out-of-memory, pen

I'm using `DashStyle.Dash` while rendering my hierarchy of objects. My application uses `Graphics.Transform` extensively and I find that at some scale values (including a scale of 100%) and some angles of rotation, `Graphics.DrawLine` throws `OutOfMemoryException` when using a pen with `DashStyle.Dash`. Using Google I found that this is a [well-known](http://www.google.com/search?q=DashStyle+Outofmemory) [problem](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.drawing/browse_thread/thread/c52a43702fccaab8/838a26535bf6e2e6). Microsoft tells us that this is not a [blocking](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=96831) [issue](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=96793). So far, I have not found a workaround for this problem.

What are my options?

Comment: I assume you're Disposing of the Pen?  And one of the articles mentioned said to avoid duplicate points in Graphics.DrawLine*s*.  You are using the singular version, correct?  You might post some code; maybe that will help get some answers.

Comment: You definitely have to Dispose all your GDI+ objects. I have had many problems when I didn't, and one of them was an Out of Memory exception.

Comment: Another idea is to take a profiler and see what's may be going on with the code, if it's a memory leak for example, and help you to solve it.

Comment: I am of the opinion that the memory in question here is that of the graphics card. And I think the problem is that I was caching pens between WM_PAINT events which some have mentioned as a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered the same issue.  Upon further investigation I discovered the following.

1. The line length was exactly the custom dash pattern length. 
   Changing the line length +/- 1 pixel avoided the error.
2. I was using `LineCapRound` and `DashCapRound`, switching to
   `LineCapSquare` and `DashCapFlat` avoided the error
3. The error came from trying flatten the path (presumably from the rounded ends)
4. The pen width was zero.

My final solution was to not draw zero width lines!